# C# restart stopwatch from an object array element

Tags: c#, arrays, stopwatch

I have a stopwatch stored in an array of objects and i want to restart it.
I am using an array of objects because my elements types keep changing always, which means that object[1] can sometimes be int, sometimes double, sometimes bool etc..., so i am not sure if i can use a class for this.

So why doesn't the stopwatch restarts in the code below?

```
public static object[] test()
    {
        object[] obj = new object[4];

        obj[0] = true;    //bool;
        obj[1] = "test";   //string;
        obj[2] = 12;   //int;
        obj[3] = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        return obj;
    }

    object[] testobject = new object[4];
    testobject = test();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(((Stopwatch)testobject[3]).Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);   
    ((Stopwatch)testobject[3]).Restart();   //Reset();
    Console.WriteLine(((Stopwatch)testobject[3]).Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: It should. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Apart from moving the lower code block into the main method and adding the necessary using statements, this code works fine as-is in a brand new console project.

Comment: Closing as not reproducible. Something else is going on that is not apparent with the information given.

Comment: This is the actual code. I just have a if statement which will check if object[0] is true and then restart the stopwatch.
In the if statement i have a console write which proves that the if statements states but the stopwatch doesn't restart within the if statement.
The stopwatch though restarts outside the if statement... I dont know what is wrong

Comment: Well i found a solution. I declared the stopwatch as a global variable and then handle it anywhere instead of having it in the array.
This however doesn't responde to the question above but since a solution was given you can close this thread.

Comment: There was a difference between your code and what you posted here. The bug is in that difference. I suggest you delete this question as it is no longer of use to anybody.